# How to remove newline characters from double quotes?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a scenario like this:

```
"abcdef
 123sq
 gh"
```

should be rearranged as "abcdef 123sq gh".

For this I used regular expressions and it works fine:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(myString, @""".*""", RegexOptions.Singleline);
if (match.Success) {
  myString= myString.Replace(match.Value, match.Value.Replace("\n", ""));
}
```

But this is not working for the scenario below:

```
"abc" "def"
asdf123456
"abc"
```

In the example above, it considers the first and last quotes and it returns the 3 lines as one.

Comment: To be complete: what should happen with newline-chars _outside_ a quoted part? In other words, are the quotes relevant?

Comment: You need to be "non-greedy" in your regex.  Use `@""".*?"""` instead to match any character (as few as possibble)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code matches any characters between quotes, but is a greedy expression - i.e. it matches as many character as possible, which sometimes means matching multiple lines.

If you use a non-greedy expression it will match a few characters a possible.  Use:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(myString, @""".*?""", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to simply replace new lines with a double quote:

```
myString = myString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\"");
```

Comment: But i want to replace new line within the double quotes

Answer (score 5):

Use [string.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) like:

For you comment:

> But i want to replace new line within the double quotes

```
myString = myString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var newstring = Regex.Replace(myString, 
                                @"\""[^\""]*?[\n\r]+[^\""]*?\""", 
                                m=>Regex.Replace(m.Value,@"[\n\r]",""));
```

This will convert

```
"abc" "d
 ef"
asdf123456
"ghi"
```

to

```
"abc" "d ef"
asdf123456
"ghi"
```

of course it works for your sample too.